# Adding results to a new Excel sheet using powershell 1.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

I have two powershell cmdlets to generate **process report** and **services report**.

eg: Get-process and Get-services

I know *export-csv c:\test.csv* will export the result to excel sheets.

But I need the result of the first cmdlet to export to the first sheet and the second cmdlet to second sheet of the same csv file.

How do I do this?

Comment: Short answer: You can't do this using `Export-Csv` because a .csv is a plain text file that doesn't support multiple sheets like a real Excel workbook.

Comment: @Filburt Can i export it to excel? or can i append to the existing result set and put it in the same sheet in csv?

Comment: It should be possible to append the second result set to the same csv - maybe needs tweaking (adding some empty lines) to look nice in Excel. Otherwise you'd have to create a real .xslx workbook and fill in the result sets using Office automation.

Comment: http://www.lucd.info/2010/05/29/beyond-export-csv-export-xls/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO the best option here is just to use excel automation. E.g. ConvertTo-Excel.ps1:

```
param (
    [ValidatePattern('\.csv$')]
    [ValidateScript({
        Test-Path $_
    })]
    [string[]]$Path
)

$FullPath = $Path | ForEach-Object {
    (Resolve-Path $_).ProviderPath
}

$First, $Rest = $FullPath

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$Book = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($First)

foreach ($Item in $Rest) {
    $Next = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Item)
    $Next.ActiveSheet.Move($Book.ActiveSheet)
}

$Excel.Visible = $true
```

You can run above script with .\ConvertTo-Excel.ps1 -Path .\services.csv, .\process.csv, ....csv
And have all csv combined, in reversed order.

HTH
Bartek